# make javascript variable update live with text input

Tags: javascript, html, live

hey this is an edited version of my first post:

Pretty much what I want to do is have a text input box that stores its contents in a javascript variable. The catch is I want it to happen live, so the variable will update automatically say, ever .2 seconds without the user needing to press a submit button. Thanks

Comment: php runs on server long before page is sent to browser so really not clear what your higher level objective is here. You can send data to server based on user events but overall question is too broad without a lot more details. Take a few minutes to help us help you by reading [ask]

Comment: Sounds like you want an Ajax call that fires on every keypress event. Except, of course, that every keypress will add a new database update. So maybe you want an onchange event. But that would require the user to click outside of the text input box to trigger the event. So maybe a timer that checks to see if the text is different? But if that fires while they are still typing you will get multiple database entries again. Hmm ... maybe you should specifically define exactly what you want to do and all the rules that govern how you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the two way data binding? Something like this: https://codepen.io/manishiitg/embed/ZYOmbB?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var mainMod = angular.module('MainApp', []);
            mainMod.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
                $scope.text = '';
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app='MainApp'>
        <div ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
          <div>
            Change Text Here: 
            <input type='text' ng-model='text' />
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>Text: {{text}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
<html>
```

You can achieve that with Angular, React and Vue.js framework, even with jQuery. Perhaps you should try one of the frameworks that solves your needs quickly.

If you choose Angular, I recommend you to make the tutorial steps, specially this part: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1#two-way-binding